# Is there a helm read-from-minibuffer functionality?

Tags: helm, minibuffer

I have an interactive command which uses `read-from-minibuffer` with a history variable.

What I now would like to have is a helm function that provides a simmilar operation: enlisting history candidates in typical helm manner and using what I typed, if there is no match, adding that to the history variable.

The "what I typed" part reminds me of `helm-find-files`, where I can select existing files and optionally create a new one.

I'm asking this to be shure that I did not overlook an existion approach, before I start to implement it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>C-r</kbd> (`helm-minibuffer-history`) when you are in minibuffer, the key binding is set in `helm-config.el` via the option `helm-minibuffer-history-key`. However, when there is no match in the helm session, helm will simply do nothing. Your idea looks useful to me, I suggest you consider filing an issue to the helm developers.

Comment: Thanks, I filed an enhancement request [#1650](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1650).

Comment: @theldoria do you manage to "adding to history variable" working? it relates to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58314/org-capture-how-to-select-history-for-a-prompt.